# First and Second derivatives

Tags: derivatives

How do I calculate the first and second derivative of this expression
$$xy + 2y - x^2$$

I'm totally lost on how to solve this.

Comment: Use "Implicit differentiation"

Comment: I know it's implicit.

Comment: There needs to be an equal sign if you're going to use implicit differentiation.

Comment: The full question is show that [d²/dx + d/dx](xy+2y-x²) = x

Answer (score 0):

Use "implicit differentiation"

You'll need the product rule for the first bit;
$$(xy)'=xy'+x'y$$
In other words;
$$(xy)'=x \times \frac{dy}{dx}+y$$
Do you need more help ?

OK.
$$(xy+2y-x^2)'=xy'+x'y+2y'-2x$$
or in other words
$$=x \frac{dy}{dx}+y+2 \frac{dy}{dx}-2x$$

Is this making sense ?

It's a little odd that this does not equal something, but I notice you used the word expression rather than equation so I've not worried about it until now.

OK.

The full questions not a problem as what's happened so far is one of the pieces. You now need to differentiate a second time to get a second piece and then make the sum of those two pieces equal $x$.

More product rule.

Do you want to try it yourself first ?

Comment: Yes, please....

Comment: The full question is show that [d²/dx + d/dx](xy+2y-x²) = x

Comment: I'll try it myself. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Well done and good luck - get back in touch if you want more help.